# How to set an item to top when I do Scroll in ListView?

Tags: android, listview, set

I have a ListView and I would like to do that when I am scrolling and an determinate item goes out of display, it set to top.

Is to do for a ListView of events. I would like the date always was visible.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean about StickListView?
[https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders](http://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders)